# Excel VBA: Copying String array to Range - String contains double quote

Tags: excel, vba

arr is an array of Strings

Using this code to copy the array to a column works fine until a String containing a double quote (") characters is reached which causes an error.

The Strings in arr are being read in from a text file and contain double quotes.

```
Application.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1) = arr
```

What's the best way to work around this?

Edit:

```
Open filePath For Input As 1
Line Input #1, NewTextLine
arr(index, 1) = textLine
```

Example of an arr() item that causes problem:

> "2016-08-30 11:12:07.9120759§3§§0§§§§§§§0§CompositeIodBuilder.Build() - Dicom Tag List for Digital X-Ray Image Storage - For Presentation:
>    Patient_s_Name Tag= "(0010,0010)" VR= "PN" VM= "1" Value= "xx xxxx^xxxx^xxx"
>    Patient_ID Tag= "(0010,0020)" VR= "

I've just noticed while copying into this post that the string contains CR and LF characters. I may have wrongly assumed it was the quotes causing problems rather than the CR and LF.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was Excel 2003 having an issue with String longer than 911 chars.

> This issue may occur if one or more of the cells in an array (range of
>   cells) contain a character string that is set to contain more than 911
>   characters.

Answer (score -1):

It's difficult to answer this without seeing your data, but, theoretically, if the value can be written to a `String` variable then it should also be writable to the sheet.

If you take this example, there is no difficulty:

```
Dim arr(1 To 2, 1 To 1) As String

arr(1, 1) = """a"""
arr(2, 1) = Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "b" & Chr(34) & Chr(34)

Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
```

However, your code to write the array to the column looks a little suspicious. Ideally you'd size the writing range to the dimensions of your array. In my example, the following code wrote a list of `#NA`.

```
Dim arr(1 To 2, 1 To 1) As String

arr(1, 1) = """a"""
arr(2, 1) = Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "b" & Chr(34) & Chr(34)

Sheet1.Columns(1).Value = arr
```

I wonder if you could a) amend your code to write array to the appropriately sized range and b) provide examples of your troublesome strings if the problem still exists.

Comment: Thanks. Have just added extra information to the post.